# C# correct implementation of a StreamWriter for a logger class

Tags: c#, logging

I'm incurring a weird problem with my project.

Here is my logger class:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace someSpace
{
    public enum LogTarget
    {
        File, Database, EventLog
    }

    public static class LogHelper
    {
        private static LogBase logger = null;
        public static void Log(LogTarget target, string path, string message)
        {
            switch (target)
            {
                case LogTarget.File:
                    logger = new FileLogger();
                    logger.Log(path, message);
                    break;
                case LogTarget.EventLog:
                    logger = new EventLogger();
                    logger.Log("", message);
                    break;
                default:
                    return;
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class LogBase
    {
        protected readonly object lockObj = new object();
        public abstract void Log(string path, string message);
    }

    public class FileLogger : LogBase
    {
        public override void Log(string path, string message)
        {
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                File.Open(path, FileMode.Open).Close();
                using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path))
                {
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(message);
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class EventLogger : LogBase
    {
        public override void Log(string path, string message)
        {
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                EventLog m_EventLog = new EventLog("");
                m_EventLog.Source = "IDGEventLog";
                m_EventLog.WriteEntry(message);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

I call the function Log like this...

```
LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.File, LOG_FILE_PATH, e.ToString());
```

I assume that by using the construct "using" in my class the stream would automatically be closed and subsequently the file would be closed and released.

That does not happen; subsequent runs of the program keep saying that the file is still in use by some process. I don't know what to do to diagnose the problem.

```
lock (lockObj)
{
    var file = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);

    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(file))
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine(message);
        streamWriter.Close();
    }

    file.Close();
}
```

Also modified this way as a comment prompted but problem is still there...

Comment: I think you should do var file = File.Open.. , then your using, then file.Close();. Otherwise it seems you close it as soon as you open it

Comment: Is there a reason you are rolling your own logger when there are many options for .NET that are full featured, robust and performant? As you are already discovering, logging is not trivial.

Comment: Yes, `File.Open(path, FileMode.Open).Close();` is very strange, particularly when you immediately reopen that same file with a `StreamWriter`.  Also, you `lock` on `lockObj`, presumably to prevent multiple calls to the same `LogBase` from trampling each other.  But then you create a new `LogBase`, with it's own `lockObj`, for _each_ `Log()` call, so this won't protect against anything.  Further, if two `Log()` calls happen at the same time to the same `LogTarget` but with _different_ `path`s, this is (attempting to) make one wait for the other, which is unnecessary.

Comment: @Crowcoder well mostly this project is a revamp of an older similar application written in Java and is more of an exercise for me because I'm more into automation I normally write PLC code and I need to keep my mind trained so I wanted to write my own... problem is my logger shouldn't be anything complicated it just needs to add some strings to a file nothing more... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each call to Log creates a new logger with its own lockObj, other loggers will not be locked out. Make lockObj a static member.

Comment: making lockObj a static seems to have solved it :) thanks! If you don't mind could you explain me why though? I'm sorry it may be a really stupid question...

Comment: A static member works as a Singleton, so at most one logger can use it.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for the explanation seems pretty simple :) it works fine now! Now some more bugs to carve out XD